# Plot figures in the same figure

Tags: matlab

I would like to plot 2 figures in the same figure:

```
A = Figure1;
B = FIgure2;

plot(A);
plot(B);
```

Is there any comand to make it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I multiple plot in one figure at Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880700/how-can-i-multiple-plot-in-one-figure-at-matlab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot 2 figures you can use subplot:

```
subplot(1,2,1), plot(A);
subplot(1,2,2), plot(B);
```